# SQLite view column name, specifically in SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlite, sqlitestudio

I have two tables in a SQLite3 database, table `a` has columns `id` (primary key) and `name`, table `b` has columns `parent` (foreign key into `a`) and `name` as well.

I create a view for the join:

```
CREATE VIEW a_b AS
    SELECT *
      FROM a
           JOIN
           b ON b.parent = a.id;
```

I can do this in SQLiteStudio and the view works. I can now run a query like:

```
SELECT * FROM a_b
```

And get the expected results. However, since both `a` and `b` have a column called `name`, the second column is renamed to `name:1` so if I want to select only that column, I need something like:

```
SELECT `name:1` FROM a_b
```

This works, but I was wondering if there's a better way to rename the columns in the view without renaming literally every column with:

```
CREATE VIEW a_b AS
    SELECT a.id as a_name, a.name as a_name, b.parent as b_parent, b.name as b_name
      FROM a
           JOIN
           b ON b_parent = a_id;
```

This works, but is clearly impractical for larger tables and also requires updating the view every time something changes about `a` or `b`. I know I can refer to the fields of the separate tables like like `a.*`, so I was looking for something like:

```
CREATE VIEW a_b AS
    SELECT a.* AS a_*, b.* AS b_*
      FROM a
           JOIN
           b ON b.parent = a.id;
```

This is clearly not code that works, but I hope it illustrates the requirement.

Is there a working, valid way to achieve this?

The best I was able to get was something like this:

```
CREATE VIEW a_b AS
    SELECT *, b.name as b_name
      FROM a
           JOIN
           b ON b.parent = a.id;
```

This at least defines an alias for `b.name`, but it also duplicates the column in the view.

Note: I'd be happy with a solution that only works in SQLiteStudio, but I suspect the solution is going to be a SQLite one, not an application-specific one.